# How can I set proxysettings for SSH in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ssh, proxy, openshift, network-connection

I am writing my bachelor thesis for a company. The company is using a proxy.
I am working with eclipse + RedHat jboss developer tools (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/827807) and OpenShift (PaaS-Cloud from RedHat).

Problem is, that RedHat is using SSH to connect to their Cloud. The port 22 is opened and I was able to config openssh to use the proxy. Unfortunately, eclipse has his own proxy settings which can be found at (Preferences - Network Connections). I can set a proxy for HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS, but not for SSH. Eclipse has three predefined schemas (http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm). But I need one new schema. For port 22.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse JBoss tools connect over HTTPS, so they should obey the proxy that is setup.  When eclipse uses git to pull/push code, it should run over SSH and obey any proxy configuration that is setup on your computer (not in Eclipse) if you have it configured correctly at the system level.

Comment: When I use ssh via the commandline it uses the proxy. When I use the Jboss Developer Tools it is trying to connect directy and is not using the Proxy. I am using Win 7 x64. The fact, that it is working over the commandline shows that it is correctly configured, isn't it?